# How to store user input parameter value to a separate table in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, parameter-passing, sql-insert

I have a stored procedure that prompt user to input four parameters, and I need to save these parameter values to one single column in a different table.

```
create procedure test (p1 in varchar2, p2 in varchar2, p3 in varchar2, p4 in varchar4) as
begin

insert into tbl1(col1)
values(concat(p1 || ' ' || p2 || ' ' || p3 || ' ' || p4);
```

I am running into error ORA-00984: column not allowed here.

Comment: There is no such data type as VARCHAR4. Not knowing what it is Oracle guesses. Oracle does not guess well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you were already told, `varchar4` is wrong datatype (though, as you used correct datatypes for other parameters, I guess it was just a typo).

You misused `concat`. I'd suggest you to use Oracle's `||` concatenation operator when dealing with more than two strings (as you did) so - just remove `concat`. Also, you're kind of missing the closing bracket (two opened one closed).

End of the procedure is missing.

Here's an example which shows what you might be looking for. See if it helps.

```
SQL> create table tbl1 (col1 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (p1 in varchar2, p2 in varchar2, p3 in varchar2, p4 in varchar2) as
  3  begin
  4    insert into tbl1(col1)
  5    values(p1 || ' ' || p2 || ' ' || p3 || ' ' || p4);
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test('Li', 'tt', 'le', 'foot');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From tbl1;

COL1
--------------------
Li tt le foot

SQL>
```